# Issues with using and calling EventHandlers

Tags: c#, event-handling, console-application

I'm using [Kellerman .NET SFTP Library](http://www.kellermansoftware.com/p-41-net-sftp-library.aspx?mode=Usage&)  and I'm having some issues using `event handlers`

According to the documentation it has the following events:

[image]

I'm interested in two of them:

1. TransferCompleteEvent
   [image]
2. FailureEvent

[image]

I would like to display a message when the transfer is complete and restart the upload if connection failed.

In my class I have the following:

```
public static void uploadToSFTP()
    {
        try
        {
            SFTP myConnection = new SFTP();
            myConnection.EnableLogging();
            myConnection.HostAddress = "servername";
            myConnection.UserName = "username";
            myConnection.Password = "password";
            myConnection.CurrentDirectory = "directory";
            myConnection.Connect();

            //UPLOADING FILE TO SFTP SERVER
            myConnection.UploadFileAsync(yesterdaysZipFile, localZipFileName);

            while (myConnection.IsBusy == true)
            {
                //PRINT HOW LONG REMAINING FROM UPLOAD
                Console.WriteLine(myConnection.EstimatedTimeRemaining);
            }

            //declaring an eventhandler  
            myConnection.TransferCompleteEvent += SFTPCompleted;
            myConnection.Disconnect();
            myConnection.Dispose();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
         }
    }
```

And then I have

```
 public static void SFTPCompleted(Object sender, TransferCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Completed");
   }
```

My problem is in this line:

```
myConnection.TransferCompleteEvent += SFTPCompleted;
```

When I use the debugger and get to this line it skips and goes to the next line it never goes to

```
   public static void SFTPCompleted(Object sender, TransferCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Completed");
   }
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

And in regards the `FailureEvent` I can't even get it to compile:

```
myConnection.FailureEvent += TransferFailed;
```

Here's the event:

```
public static void TransferFailed(Object sender, SFTP.FailureEventHandler e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("failed");
}
```

I get this compiler error:

> Error 1   No overload for 'TransferFailed' matches delegate 'KellermanSoftware.NetSFtpLibrary.SFTP.FailureEventHandler'

This is my first time using this library. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
myConnection.TransferCompleteEvent += SFTPCompleted;
```

is attaching an event handler.

You are attaching the event handler after calling `UploadFileAsync` and waiting for it to stop being busy. At this point, the event would have already fired, so you're missing out on hearing about it.

You should attach the event handler as soon as you create the `myConnection` object.

```
SFTP myConnection = new SFTP();
myConnection.TransferCompleteEvent += SFTPCompleted;
```

---

Your second problem is that you cannot attach the `TransferFailed` event. That's because you have the wrong parameters in your handler function. My guess is that it should be:

```
public static void TransferFailed(Object sender, SFTP.FailurEventArgs e)
```

Have a look at the `SFTP.FailureEventHandler` declaration. It will tell you what the parameters need to be.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. It worked when I moved it up. And using documentation, I fixed the failed event. `public static void TransferFailed(Object sender, System.Exception e)`. Thank you.